# Is every problem in NP solvable?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, undecidability, decision-problem, np

Is every $\sf NP$-problem solvable or are there problems that have no working algorithm to solve but have algorithms to verify?

Comment: What do you mean by "solvable"? What are your own thoughts, what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Working from the "machine" definition (that a problem is in $\mathcal{NP}$ if and only if it can be decided by a *non-deterministic* Turing Machine in polynomial time), we can take a similar approach as in Bill Province's verifier based answer.

Given a problem $P \in \mathcal{NP}$, there is, by definition, a non-deterministic Turing Machine $M_{P}$ that correctly decides whether $x \in P$ or not in time bounded by $|x|^{c}$ for every $x \in \Sigma^{\ast}$ and some fixed $c \in \mathbb{N}$.

The gap between this and a "working" algorithm is the non-deterministic steps that $M_{P}$ makes during the computation. For each non-deterministic step, there is a finite number of choices that $M_{P}$ can possible make (even sticking rigidly to Turing Machines, there are at most $k=|\Gamma\times\Sigma\times Q\times \{L,R\}|$ possible transitions from the current state).

We can then simulate the non-determinism by branching on each of these possibilities or exploring each in turn. Given that $M_{P}$ performs $O(|x|^{c})$ steps, even if every single step were non-deterministic, the number of steps in this exhaustive search of the possibilities would be $O(k^{|x|^{c}})$ - unpleasantly large, but certainly finite.

Answer (score 3):

Every problem in $\sf NP$ is decidable (solvable). Just try out all possible "witnesses" for the verification algorithm. This can be understood as a brute force algorithm over the witnesses.

There is one caveat, though. You have to know the maximal length of the witness encodings you have to try out. Since the problem is in $\sf NP$ you know that there exists some $k>0$ such that it suffices to consider encodings of length $O(n^k)$, for $n$ being the length of your input. You can now set up a brute force algorithm for each $k\in \mathbf{N}$.

As pointed out in the comments, you might also want to go over all constants $c$ hidden in the big-O notation. However, since you test *all* $k$, you will find a $k'>k$ such that $n^{k'}$ dominates $cn^k$ for all constants $c$.

Under these algorithms there *exists* one (in fact infinitely many) algorithm that decides the problem. So the sketch of the proof I gave you is not constructive unless you know the $k$.

Comment: (1) I am afraid that the second paragraph is stated imprecisely.  If you only know k, you cannot test all certificates of length O(n^k) because of the O-notation.  If, say, you know k such that all yes-instances have a certificate of length at most n^k+k, then you can test all certificates.  (2) I do not think that it is usual terminology to say that this proof is not constructive.  It is as constructive as k in the assumption, and as I understand it, this is what people usually mean by constructive.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I have extended my answer. Whether this is constructive or not depends on how you interpret what is meant by "constructive". I notice that many students are confused when you present this idea and then ask "but how do you know the $k$"? I just wanted to stress out that you do not need to know the $k$ to prove the statement.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that if a problem is in NP, it is indeed solvable.

A language L in NP, by definition allows for the existence of a "witness" machine M such that the following is true: There is a polynomial p(n) such that if S is in L then there is a certificate C such that M(S, C) accepts in an amount of time bounded above by p(length(S)).  Without loss of generality, we can assume that C is expected to be just a string of 1s and 0s.

Therefore, if we know that a language L is in NP, we know that such a witness machine M exists with the provided polynomial.  We might not have a means of finding M or its polynomial, but we know that such a machine exists. So theoretically, using M, we can decide L for a given input S: just consider all possible certificates with length less than or equal to p(length(S)) with the given machine.  For a given S, the number of strings is finite, and therefore decidable.